# Jquery not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to just call a alert when a button is click with jquery and I am not sure if it's my syntax is wrong or something else can anyone point me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BETA BLOCKER NET</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.j"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/registration.js" ></script>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/override.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/blackbox.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RB').on('click', function(){
        alert('here');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="index" class="navbar" >
        <div class="navbar-inner">
         <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><button id="RB">Registration</button></li>
        <ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working here **:==>** http://jsfiddle.net/HfcZ3/ `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is incorrect. Should be .js.  Not .j

Comment: Unless this is a type just for the post. It works in your fiddle, because it resources the js files from the fidldle API, not your reference.

Comment: No problem! I have been writting code prefessionaly for many years, and since I was around 10. One thing is certain, me, nor anyone else will ever write code, without having a bug or two. Comes along with the territory, and they always seem to be the little ones that get ya! They seem correct at a glance, as your eyes are expecting the right grammatical context, but then you see where it is.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.j"
```

Does not equal

```
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
```

which would work